# Window.open inconsistent height for browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple pop-up window using this JS code:

```
window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=400,height=545,innerHeight=500, left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable");
```

The resultant pop-up window is showing different heights for different browsers. I checked the `window.innerHeight` through console on different browsers, and this is the result:

safari: `window.innerHeight`= 455

chrome: `window.innerHeight`= 500

IE: `window.innerHeight`= 549

Firefox: `window.innerHeight`= 544

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwL504ys/) link.

I need the pop-up with the height of 500px. How can I do that across all browsers.

Comment: 1: You cannot set innerHeight 2: You should not have spaces in the parameters 3: Browsers calculate statusbars and scroll bars differently so you are likely not able to do what you want with window.open. Can you use a modal div?

Comment: 1. I set innerHeight, using the suggestions given in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462374/window-open-height-isnt-the-same-in-google-chrome-as-other-browsers) 2. Removed the space, still the same issue

Comment: Requirements won't allow use of modal

Answer (score 2):

Resizing the window after opening may achieve better size accuracy:

```
var win = window.open("about:blank" "popupwindow",  // about:blank for demo
  "width=400,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable");
// adjust size;
win.resizeBy( 400 - win.innerWidth, 500-win.innerHeight);
```

requests a window 400 x 500 pixels and then resizes the content area to make sure. Treatment or even recognition of innerHeight and width settings may differ between browsers.

***However***

Popup windows are subject to user preferences and popup blockers. For example I have IE set to open popups in a new tab (the code above does not open a new window), Firefox to always include the location bar, and regard any site that sets out to circumvent a popup blocker as malicious. You may wish to draw this to the attention of those setting the requirements.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the code you mentioned, but it's not showing the desired results. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nwL504ys/3/). Can you please see what I'm doing wrong in the fiddle, and kindly updated the fiddle?

Comment: You logged the window size before  resize **:D**  Try it now... (I've only tested in Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=400,innerHeight=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable");
```

You can't predict the height of window. It's depends on user preferences.
But you only need the innerHeight

Comment: yes, that's why I'm only checking the innerHeight property, and there are marked differences in that across different browsers.

Comment: @anwartheravian remove the height. Just keep the innerHeight. When you have height and innerHeight, Only height would applied. That's my changed code

Comment: Removed height, and made `innerHeight` to 500. This is the result of window.innerHeight on different browsers: IE: 604
Safari: 455
Chrome: 500
Firefox: 544