# window.open height parameter is different in Opera on Windows

Tags: javascript

Using the same code, the Windows version of Opera and the macOS version of Opera open new windows with different sizes when using `window.open`. The code is the one below:

```
    var width  = 600;
    var height = 550;
    var leftPosition = window.innerWidth + (window.screenX - (width + 60));
    var topPosition = window.innerHeight + window.screenY - (height + 60);
    my_window = window.open(url, 'NewWindow', 'scrollbars=0' + 
                                    ',width=' + width + 
                                    ',height=' + height +  
                                    ',left=' + leftPosition + 
                                    ',top=' + topPosition);
```

I would mention other browsers, but as far as I know, that same code works properly in Chrome and Firefox, opening a window with the same size of macOS's Opera (if it is not the same size, it's approximate enought). In macOS, Opera opens a window with the following properties:

- outerHeight: 609
- innerHeight: 550

While in Windows, Opera opens a window with the following properties:

- outerHeight: 543
- innerHeight: 462

I tried using `resizeBy`, as mentioned in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36658167/4370893):

```
    var width  = 600;
    var height = 550;
    var leftPosition = window.innerWidth + (window.screenX - (width + 60));
    var topPosition = window.innerHeight + window.screenY - (height + 60);

    var baseWidth  = 200;
    var baseHeight = 200;
    my_window = window.open(url, 'NewWindow', 'scrollbars=0' + 
                                    ',width=' + baseWidth + 
                                    ',height=' + baseHeight +  
                                    ',left=' + leftPosition + 
                                    ',top=' + topPosition);
    my_window.resizeBy(width - baseWidth, height - baseHeight);
```

After that change, in macOS, Opera opens a window with the following properties:

- outerHeight: 551
- innerHeight: 492

While in Windows, Opera opens a window with the following properties:

- outerHeight: 543
- innerHeight: 462

So that change makes their sizes closer, but I wanted to set the innerHeight, not the outerHeight. I also tried that:

```
    my_window = window.open(url, 'NewWindow', 'scrollbars=0' + 
                                    ',width=' + width + 
                                    ',height=' + height +  
                                    ',left=' + leftPosition + 
                                    ',top=' + topPosition);
    setTimeout(function(){
        my_window.resizeBy(width - my_window.innerWidth, height - my_window.innerHeight);
    },100);
```

In Windows, Opera opened a window with the following properties:

- outerHeight: 632
- innerHeight: 550

Which is exactly what I wanted, but it makes the window gigantic in macOS (without setTimeout it still looks gigantic, but in the other hand, the Windows version becomes gigantic as well).

I could create a condition for Windows's Opera to use the method above only on it and leave the original code for all the rest, but it doesn't look like a proper solution for me. Does anyone knows a more proper method to do it?

**EDIT:** That's the best method that I could achieve so far.

```
    var crossBrowserWindowOpen = function(url, windowId, width, height, left, top) {
        var my_window = window.open(url, windowId, 'scrollbars=0' + 
                        ',width=' + width + ',height=' + height +  
                        ',left='  + left  + ',top='    + top);

        var setWindowSize = function(my_window) {
            if (my_window.innerHeight === 0) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    setWindowSize(my_window);
                },100);
                return;
            }
            if (Math.abs(height - my_window.innerHeight) >= 5) {
                my_window.resizeBy(width - my_window.innerWidth, height - my_window.innerHeight);
            }
        };
        setWindowSize(my_window);

        return my_window;
    }
    my_window = crossBrowserWindowOpen(url, 'NewWindow', 
                                width, height, leftPosition, topPosition);
```

That method seems to work across every browser, but it doesn't look that good, since using setTimeout until the window appears is a really hacky approach. Does anyone know of a better approach?

**EDIT 2:** Updated code above with minor fix for Ubuntu's Chrome.

**EDIT 3:** Just to clarify: tested it in macOS (Safari, Chrome, Opera and Firefox), Windows (IE, Edge, Opera, Firefox and Chrome) and Ubuntu (Chrome, Firefox and Opera). The only one which still has an issue is Ubuntu's Firefox, which is slightly smaller than all the rest. I was totally not expected OS-specific bugs, but here they are.

Comment: Forget the idea that you could still have absolute control over popup sizes these days. My browser is configured to not even open them as popups, but simply as normal tabs - so you have no control whatsoever regarding size.

Comment: In those I may don't have control, but for those which still open as new windows, there should be a proper method to set a window height. The fact that this can't be achieved without a hack nowadays is truly confusing

Comment: @vitormm *"The fact that this can't be achieved without a hack nowadays is truly confusing"* - I think you'll find less and less support for popups moving forward, which is a good thing IMO.

Comment: @vitormm Popups used to be a lot more common.  Thankfully, they're disappearing.  To be frank, it isn't confusing at all.  No one likes popups, so browser vendors are disinclined to focus much time on them, and some popup features have been actively deprecated.  I also have popups open in a new tab.

Comment: Still, in some cases they are still the chosen approach. Like Paypal, which still shows a pop up window for logging in when you choose to pay with Paypal in most websites. The same happens in some websites with Facebook login, when you select to login with it. With big companies like those doing that, it's confusing that the support for popups is dying